# VBA MS Word - Insert all mail merge fields into Word doc at once

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

Currently MS Word only allows for the insertion of 1 mail merge field at a time. I am looking for a VBA code that would allow me to insert all merge fields into a Word doc at once and/or a code that would input a mail merge field where the name of the same mail merge text appears in the doc.

For the second possibility I have found the following code that allows the user to convert text that matches a mail merge name into a mail merge field one at a time ( http://apsona.com/blog/how-to-quickly-create-merge-fields-in-word/ ). I am dealing with a data source that contains thousands of mail merge fields so ideally I would want to do this for all of them at once or create a loop or something similar.

```
Sub MakeMergeField()

Selection.Copy
Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:= _
"MERGEFIELD """ + Selection.Text + """, PreserveFormatting:=True"

End Sub
```

Comment: «Currently MS Word only allows for the insertion of 1 mail merge field at a time» While that is true as far as it goes, there is no need to close the mergefields dialogue box between insertions. Unlike a simple field insertion macro, that allows you to insert the fields out of order, so you don't have to re-arrange them afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no functionality in Word to insert all merge fields at once, so you need to insert them individually, in a loop.

The following does that, separating each merge field by a space.

(Note: Normally, when you insert something in Word, the target `Range` encompasses what was inserted - not so with merge fields. That's why `Range.Start` is moved to the end of the document after each insertion, before adding a space to it. Then the `Range` needs to be "collapsed" beyond that space before doing the next insertion.)

```
Sub InsertAllMergeFields()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim rng As word.Range
    Dim mm As word.MailMergeDataField

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.content
    If doc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType <> wdNotAMergeDocument Then
        For Each mm In doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields
            doc.MailMerge.Fields.Add rng, mm.NAME
            rng.Start = doc.content.End
            rng.InsertAfter " "
            rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```