# Replace text with matching Mail Merge Field

Tags: vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I would like to create a macro in MS Word that when run searches the document for text that appears in the body of the document that matches the mail merge field name. Once identified it would change the text in the document to the actual matching mail merge field name. For example, if there was a mail merge field named "project_date" and in the Word document there was the text "project_date" the macro would turn the text into the actual mail merge field "project_date".

Ideally, the macro would do this for all mail merge fields that exists at once.

Below is as far as I have come with formulating my desired code.

I found this code here ( https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2007/how-do-i-replace-words-in-a-document-with-a-mail/da323980-7c7d-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5 ) but it only will do one specified mail merge field at a time.

```
Dim oRng As Range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
With oRng.Find
    Do While .Execute(FindText:="(Player 1)")
        oRng.Fields.Add oRng, wdFieldMergeField, "Player_1", False
        oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    Loop
End With
```

I recorded this myself, but am not sure how to search and replace text with desired merge field.

```
With Selection.Find
        .Text = "project_name"
        .Replacement.Text = "project_name"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
```

Comment: @Cindy Meister - I looked at how I would combined both together and I think what was making it hard was not knowing the code language. Thank you so much for not just doing this for me, but for showing me how you got to your conclusion. I can't wait to try it out, google every name in the code so I understand how it works and to keep on learning VBA. I have been pushing going all out into vba as I heard MS might be incorporating Python as I second coding language along side VBA and that Python would be easier to learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution for this combines [the code for inserting all merge fields](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50031198/3077495) into a document with the basic code you found / recorded. Inserting the merge field is moved into the Function that searches the field names in the document. I've set the function up to return the number of times the field is inserted.

The tricky, or special, part of the Function is setting up the Range after a successful Find to continue the search. The end-point of a merge field is still within the merge field, thus the line `oRng.MoveStart wdCharacter, 2` is required after collapsing the Range. If the Range stays within the field, the merge field name inside it will be found again, and again, and again...

```
Sub InsertAllMergeFieldsAtPlaceholders()
    Dim doc As word.Document
    Dim rng As word.Range
    Dim mm As word.MailMergeDataField

    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set rng = doc.content
    If doc.MailMerge.MainDocumentType <> wdNotAMergeDocument Then
        For Each mm In doc.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields
            Debug.Print ReplaceTextWithMergeField(mm.NAME, rng) & " merge fields inserted for " & mm.NAME
            Set rng = doc.content
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Function ReplaceTextWithMergeField(sFieldName As String, _
                                   ByRef oRng As word.Range) As Long
    Dim iFieldCounter As Long
    Dim fldMerge As word.Field
    Dim bFound As Boolean

    With oRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Forward = True
        .wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        bFound = .Execute(findText:=sFieldName)
    End With
    Do While bFound
        iFieldCounter = iFieldCounter + 1
        Set fldMerge = oRng.Fields.Add(oRng, wdFieldMergeField, sFieldName, False)
        Set oRng = fldMerge.result
        oRng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        oRng.MoveStart wdCharacter, 2
        oRng.End = oRng.Document.content.End
        bFound = oRng.Find.Execute(findText:=sFieldName)
    Loop
    ReplaceTextWithMergeField = iFieldCounter
End Function
```

Comment: I tested the code out today it works well with single file  column charts, but once you add three of more columns wide by say 12 columns long WORD does not respond for a very long time. I tested with only 100 data fields as I was trying to figure out why it was not working with my semi-large chart in the beginning.

Comment: @DonDon I'm really not sure we're thinking of the same thing with the term "chart". I think of "bar chart", "pie chart", etc. And I have a hard time imagining what "thre or more *columns* wide by say 12 *columns* long means. But the larger the collection, the slower Word will be - especially when working with another application (Excel). For this particular question, however, it would be optimal to work with ONLY the field names (column headers?), with only one or two records. Once the main merge document is set up, then connect it to a "full" data source.

Comment: I meant a table here as well. For example, if one were to insert a table in Word and enter the field names into the table. Or if I were to copy and paste a group of cells from excel to word (depending how I pasted it) the information would appear in a table in word.