# Replace prefaced text with matching Mail Merge Field

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to do a series of report migrations. I will be copying a lot of fields from Crystal ({command.somename}) to Word.

I would like to then replace Command.somename into a Mergefield somename, where the name is the dynamic variable.

I have read a similar post to change a specific word [Replace text with matching Mail Merge Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50122503/replace-text-with-matching-mail-merge-field). What do I alter to have that word search be dynamic for the word after "*Command.*"?

Example  change command.srent to a mergefield { mergefield srent }  (<<srent>>).

Comment: I think with the code from the other article I could use, if I can figure out how to search for the words that contains "command.", delete "command.", and search for the word that is left.  But I would want to do this for every instance of "command." in one script and not have to run it several times.  The number of instances of a given command.somename will be unknown.  Maybe a search/replace of the first command.somename and then find next "command" and replace?

Comment: Find first instance of Command.  EX: Command.DGARBAGEDISPOSALD and change to a merge field  { MERGEFIELD GARBAGEDISPOSAL }.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFld As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "\{*\}"
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
    StrFld = "MERGEFIELD " & Replace(Replace(.Text, "{command.", ""), "}", "")
    .Text = vbNullString
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Duplicate, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, Text:=StrFld, Preserveformatting:=False
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The problem right now is that It is finding all instances and creating a MERGEFIELD but it is not populated with the remaining name, after replacing the text Command. I am obviously missing something.

Comment: The code works fine for the example you gave. The code you've posted, however, indicates you're working with "Command\.", not "command.". The two are fundamentally different. To limit the F/R to 'fields' starting with "{Command\." or "{command.", change: .Text = "\{*\}" to .Text = "\{[Cc]ommand*\}" and change Replace(Replace(.Text, "{command.", ""), "}", "") to Replace(Replace(Replace(.Text, "{Command\.", ""),{command.", ""), "}", "")

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue with the use of `.Words.Parent`.  The issue with the suggested code was that it was returning the search `.Text` not the found word within the search text.  Then iterating through each instance with variable `i` I was able to isolate each found word within the found range and replace that word with a `{mergefield }`. Once done a quick `F9` in Word and it updated all the new mergefields.  Thanks for the help and direction @macropod is was very helpful

```
Sub ReplaceCommandtoMergefield()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFld As String
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Text = "Command\."
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = True
  End With
  Do While .Find.Execute
   'MsgBox .Words.Parent
    StrFld = Replace(.Words.Parent, "Command.", "")
    .Words.Parent.Delete
    .Fields.Add Range:=.Duplicate, Type:=wdFieldMergeField, Text:=StrFld, Preserveformatting:=True
    .Text = vbNullString
    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  Loop
End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @macropod -- any idea why the search filter or "\{*\}" wouldn't find anything?